# how to allow home page to access without login and when any userlogin restrict access to home page to for that user in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.6

I am trying to write code in such a manner that, when anyone logs in to my sight with user role=merchant he will not allow accessing my home page and when anyone login with user role=customer then he will allow accessing the home page, rather than that anyone without a login can visit my home page

Comment: sorry for my bad title tag:

Answer (score 0):

You can define your rule in isAuthorized action in `/src/Controller/AppController.php`

```
// src/Controller/AppController.php



 public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
// Assuming home function as your home page
        if ($this->request->getParam('action') == 'home' && $user['role'] == 'customer' ) {
            return true;
        }
       return false;
    }
```

[Cakephp -> Authentication and Authorization -> Authorization (who’s allowed to access what)](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what)